# Is Pair Solitaire on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Just saw [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28147/pair-solitaire-game-problem) question, which got me Googling. Apparently:

> "[Pair Solitaire](http://pairsolitaire.com/) is a new kind of solitaire, designed for mobile."

I'm a bit confused about this game. My question would be:

1. is this a computer adaptation of a card game, or
2. is this a computer game that happens to use playing cards?

Because if it's the latter, the question should be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it is not on topic as it is designed as a computer (mobile in this case) and not as a physical card game. While it should be possible to play it as a physical card game it seems that most of the mechanics (especially the one in the question) are all designed around the mobile gaming part of this. It seems that it would be a better question on Arcade but seeing how it is a bad question it should just be closed and not migrated.

Comment: I think the people at Arqade are most suited to judge the quality of the question. I can't pretend to know anything about this game so I can't tell if it's obvious to a player what this question is about.

Comment: @freekvd generally if a question has been closed on one site it isn't reopened and migrated to another site,

Comment: That's not what I meant. This question has been closed for being 'unclear'. I suspect the voters didn't understand the question because it's about computer gaming. The game has built-in challenges to unlock and they're hidden behind a question mark. This person is asking what's behind the last question mark. You need to know this to understand the question, let alone answer it.

Comment: @freekvd First you should give the voters here more credit, second there is nothing stopping the person who asked the question from asking it again on Arcade, third if you feel strongly about this why not cast a reopen vote so the process to reopen and migrate it can get started

Comment: Sorry I guess I am a bit frustrated. I did feel strongly about this, and I did vote to migrate to Arqade which started the close vote. Others then rounded up that vote using other reasons.